# Unable to install pyenchant-1.6.5 for python 2.7 on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, python-2.7, pyenchant

I am not able to install pyenchant for python 2.7 on my Max OSX Lion.  I get an error using the dmg installer.  I get an error stating that /opt/local/Library/Frameworks Python 2.7 is required.

My python 2.7 is installed in /Library/Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

That installer you are using is expecting there to be a macports version of python installed ( the /opt  location ).

Just try installing it via [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or pip

```
easy_install pyenchant
```

Or

```
pip install pyenchant
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install pyenchant on Mac OS X Maverick using non-Homebrew Python by using this procedure. It is likely to work for Mac OS X Mountain Lion as well.

The pyenchant Python library has four prerequisites: gettext, glib, libiconv, and enchant.

Install the first two using Homebrew: `brew install gettext` and `brew install glib`

Install the second two using the source code, or using the source from the pyenchant-bdist-osx-source tarball (https://github.com/downloads/rfk/pyenchant/pyenchant-bdist-osx-sources-1.6.5.tar.gz):

```
tar xzf libiconv-1.3.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.31.1
./configure
make
make install
cd ..
```

and

```
tar xzf enchant-1.6.0.tar.gz
cd enchant-1.6.0
./configure
make
make install
cd ..
```

Now you've got all the prerequisites, so you can install pyenchant directly using setuptools. Download the source tarball (http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.5.tar.gz) and extract it. Now use setup.py to build and install pyenchant:

```
tar xzf pyenchant-1.6.5.tar.gz
cd pyenchant-1.6.5
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
cd ..
```

And you should be all finished!