# "enchant C library not found" while installing pyenchant using pip on OSX

Tags: macos, pip, pyenchant

I typed in `pip install pyenchant` into my shell, but it raised two Traceback errors:

## 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/q4/l70hdqjd5db2n2bdj69qrwz40000gq/T/pip_build_prernauppal/pyenchant/setup.py", line 195, in <module>
    import enchant
  File "enchant/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from enchant import _enchant as _e
  File "enchant/_enchant.py", line 133, in <module>
    raise ImportError("enchant C library not found")
ImportError: enchant C library not found
```

## 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

    File "/private/var/folders/q4/l70hdqjd5db2n2bdj69qrwz40000gq/T/pip_build_prernauppal/pyenchant/setup.py", line 195, in <module>

        import enchant

    File "enchant/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>

        from enchant import _enchant as _e

     File "enchant/_enchant.py", line 133, in <module>

        raise ImportError("enchant C library not found")

ImportError: enchant C library not found

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q4/l70hdqjd5db2n2bdj69qrwz40000gq/T/pip_build_prernauppal/pyenchant
```

I have python 2.7 default installed on my mac, but it still isn't working. I have already looked at [Unable to install pyenchant-1.6.5 for python 2.7 on Mac OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236332/unable-to-install-pyenchant-1-6-5-for-python-2-7-on-mac-osx-lion) but it doesn't answer my question, as `easy_install pyenchant` raises even more errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install `enchant`, which is a C library. You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), to do this kind of package management. Just enter:

```
brew install enchant
```

Before trying to pip install `pyenchant` and you should be fine.

Comment: It still didn't work... the `brew` was successful, but the `pip install pyenchant` raised the same errors.

Comment: @aj8uppal sounds like you've got some permissions messed up (pretty common on mac). I would suggest trying both with and without sudo for both of the commands: `brew install enchant`, and `pip install pyenchant`

Answer (score 10):

Try this - It worked for me on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install libenchant1c2a
```

Comment: Although the question was about OSX, this helped me with a docker build. tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Try either sudo pip install or sudo easy install.

Answer (score 1):

> [nltk_data] Error loading enchant: Package 'enchant' not found in

No. if you get this problem,  you are supposed to install it like this:

```
$ sudo easy_install pyenchant
```

it is not an nltk package, it is a package on its own.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo easy_install
```

`sudo` because MAC permissions are usually messed up

Answer (score 0):

Try a `pip` install, an `easy_install`, and a `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the NLTK package. That is how you get Pyenchant running. But if your building a grammar checker, pyenchant is not advisable because it only grammar checks two words. You should consider building a grammar checker on your own by starting with an autocomplete word completion from here: 
[How to code autocompletion in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821661/how-to-code-autocompletion-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

For windows: download the required .exe file based on version from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyenchant/
 and pip install pyenchant